# How to prevent xcode to create app id automaticaly?

Tags: ios, xcode

xcode generates app ID automatically and it's problem when working with multiple accounts with... Xcode registers app ID at wrong account.

When does xcode generate this? When I press build or when i check "automatically manage signing"?

Should I use only "Team member" accounts in xcode? and Team admin only for web?

Comment: uncheck "automatically manage signing"

Comment: when you open project that have it checked.. will it automatically create the app id... etc? or when i press build?

Comment: I think when you press build. not sure ant that